# How does Outlook test e-mails work?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When you're creating a new account and you send yourself a "test-email", how does it work? It only shows the time down to the minute so if you have it working, then change some settings, if the test e-mail isn't sent/received a second time, the system could be fooled into thinking the first success was for the second time?

Answer (score 1):

There are two steps:

1. Checking incoming mail (only logging in, not downloading)
2. Sending a test message

After the 2nd step, no further checks are needed. Outlook is only checking if the mailing system **accepts** a test message, but it doesn't check for further delivery.

[image: Outlook test message screenshot]